# how can i use npm start on mac os catalina?

Tags: macos, npm, macos-catalina

I have created a new react application using `npx create-react-app my-app`.  I did this without any problem on mac os Majave, 10.14.6, my work computer. Using `npm start`, the web server and application starts as expected.

When I do the same on my home computer, running mac os Catalina 10.15, I am able to create the application, however, when I start it using `npm start`, it fails.  There are serval suggested steps to fix the problem which I have followed but it still fails.

I suspect the server is 32 bit, which will not run on mac os 10.15 but have not seen any documentation.  Is this supported on mac os Catalina?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to create a new react app using: `npx create-react-app my-app`. It worked perfectly. I then saw this message on the screen (see screenshot).

I then ran `yarn start` as suggested which opened a browser with the React website. Also tried with `npm run start`, also worked like a charm (see the other screenshot).
I am using:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.1
- yarn 1.19.1
- npx / npm 6.4.1
- node 10.13.0

Maybe check if you have the same versions and try again. Otherwise please be more specific and post the exact error message you see.

[image]

[image]

Comment: After making some changes does the HMR kick in and reload your browser? I am using macOS Catalina and since i upgraded when i make some changes to the App it does not show. I  have to stop and run yarn start again.